# XSLT and CQWP : EventDate is always empty

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I am trying to create an xsl template for displaying a calendar and am having an issue pulling the event date out of the calendar items.

Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:template name="DateCustomStyle" match="Row[@Style='DateCustomStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
<xsl:variable name="day" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Created),1033,'dd')" />
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
<h3 class="thisweek-title">This Week</h3>
</xsl:if>
    <div class="thisweek-item">
                <div class="thisweek-date">
                    <span class="thisweek-abbr">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate),1033,'ddd')"/>
                    </span>
            <span class="thisweek-day">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@EventDate),1033,'dd')"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="thisweek-events">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                    <span>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/></span>
                </li>
                        </ul>

                </div>
        </div>
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*)=0">
<div class="thisweek-opencalendar"><a href="/Lists/Calendar">Open Calendar</a></div>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

For some reason, the EventDate (which is the internal field name for Start Time) is empty. I have tested it with Created to make sure it was parsing correctly, which it is.

I am at a complete loss. I know for a fact that the date is in there, but its just not coming through.

*Note*

I have also replaced EventDate with Start_x0020_Time, which is the display name of the field. Also yielded nothing.

If anyone has a suggestion I would be grateful

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, did you add the reference for the date-formats in the top in the ItemStyle.xsl file?

```
xmlns:ddwrt=http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime
```

And this is how i'm using the EventDate in our SharePoint. I think the problem is that you are trying to convert the date into a string. Try to remove that and try this instead.

```
<span class="thisweek-day">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@EventDate, 1033, 'dd')"/>
                </span>
```